# Creating a flat db for connecting Power BI

Tags: database, powerbi, reporting, paas

Need a separate Reporting Db for displaying Power BI reports.
We need to keep both the transactional and Reporting data in sync every 1 hour.
We have our DB in Azure Sql and want our reporting to be on some cheap storage.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you really ask, but I guess you are looking for recommendation. I think that Azure SQL Database could do the job for you. The lower tiers should be sufficient for you, especially if you store pre-calculated and pre-aggregated data in this reporting database. For example I'm having couple basic tier (5 DTU) databases, that supports like hundred Power BI reports with about 850 visuals and daily ETL. Basic tier [costs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) about $5 per month and it is up to 2GB. If 5 DTUs can't satisfy your needs, you can go to 10 DTU (S0, 250GB) for $15 or 20 DTU (S1) for $30 (and of course, even higher, in case you need more).

Comment: Yes asking for recommendations as you have mentioned  for storing pre calculated and pre- aggregated data. Question is how this reporting database get synced with live data every defined hour?

Comment: You will need to implement some kind of ETL process. Usually SSIS is used for on premise. For Azure you may take a look at Azure Data Factory (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/) or make something custom, let's say using Azure Automation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-intro).